# Titanium - IOS debugging via iOs Simulator

Tags: javascript, ios, debugging, titanium, ios-simulator

Is there a better way to debug with Titanium then I am doing currently?
Im running my project always in the iOs simulator. The problem is for every little adjustment I am doing I have to close the iOs iPhone simulator and debug again.

Is there a faster way to debug? It takes a lot of time to develop an application when I always have to close and restart the simulator.

What are u guys doing to test on iOs?

( Loading the Android simulator takes also very long to test ).

Best regards,

Duikboot

Answer (score 1):

If you want proper debugging in Titanium, Titanium Studio now offers iOS and Android debugging. You can view a video guide on how to here: https://vimeo.com/21949107

As for 'debugging', as in making minor changes and relaunching the simulator. You need to recompile everything you've written in Titanium into C, which is why you're required to relaunch the simulator.

For stylistic changes, I suggest checking out http://www.kraniumjs.com - as they have an awesome  framework set up that will socket in style changes. Great for UI Tweaking.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you load the iOS simulator, but it should be very fast. Sure as hell don't build your titanium project, and load the whole thing in xCode, and run the simulator from there.

For iOS & Android, run on simulator from Titanium Studio. Usually (at least at my machine) this takes about 10-20 seconds. Android tends to be a little bit slower sometimes.

iOS simulator will automatically close when re-deploying to simulator. Best is to use Titanium Studio 2.0. (the newest one)

Android simulator doesn't close, but closes the application, and re-installs it on the simulator.

This is a quick process, as said above.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to restart your iOS Titanium app in the simulator without having to close the simulator.

Since the app running in the simulator is actually symlink-ing your original .js files, you can often use ios-sim to restart your app with the updated source code.

The command line for using ios-sim is a bit of a pain so I created a tool to automate the process

http://tech.frontseat.org/2013/08/titanium-refresh-make-code-changes-without-rebooting-the-simulator/